# ConstraintLayout: view in vertical chain should wrap content up to 1/3 of the space

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have two RecyclerViews `view_a` and `view_b` vertically on top of each other within a ConstraintLayout.
Width: easy, match_parent. My problem is the height.

The bottom `view_b` should wrap its content, and expand up to 1/3 of the space.
The top `view_a` should fill the remaining space.

E.g. if view_b contains only 1 item, I want it to fill only 1/10th of the height, and view_a should fill the remaining 9/10. But when view_b contains 1000 items, it should fill 1/3 (and scroll to show the hidden items), leaving 2/3 for view_a.

I tried the following. However, this only achieves a fixed 2:1 ratio of the views.
If `view_b` is smaller than 1/3, it still fills the entire 1/3 at the bottom and does not wrap its content.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/view_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view_b"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/view_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_a"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I also tried adding `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"` to `view_b`.
But then it always wraps its content and expands beyond the 1/3 and becomes too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting the below attributes in the `view_b (RecyclerView)`:

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_max="wrap"
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```

From the above attributes if the `view_b (RecyclerView)` contains smaller amount of data from the 1/3 of the screen it will wrap to its content, but if contains a large amount of data and exceeds the 1/3 of the screen it will get the maximum height to be the 1/3 of the screen, leaving always the remaining space to `view_a (RecyclerView)`.

The final xml should be like the below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/view_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/view_b"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/view_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Guideline` like blow:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/view_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/view_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it out, but view_b is still fixed at 0.7. view_b doesn’t wrap its height to its contents when its contents are smaller than 0.3 (which is what I want).